# Is there any way to read the current level of volume being sent to the speakers?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a volume leveler so that I don't have to constantly jocky the volume down during loud scenes and up during dialog. Ads on Pandora blasting my ear drums is also annoying.

Is there any way to get what volume is being sent to the speakers? If I can get that number I can turn the volume up and down programatically.

Comment: There is no single correct answer, volume control changed significantly in Vista with per-application volume control.  The underlying api is WASAPI, Windows Audio Session api.  Which is very difficult to use from C#.  You can probably google a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the PInvoke command waveOutSetVolume for this purpose:

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/waveOutSetVolume.html

There is also a corresponding waveOutGetVolume to read the current volume.